# Can't set date range for Jquery UI calendar

Tags: jquery-ui

I am having problems getting my head around the syntax to set the date range for the JqueryUI calendar.

this...

```
$(function() {
    $('#DOB').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'd MM yy',
        minDate: new Date(1900, 11 - 1, 6)

    });
});
```

is strangely giving me a range of the years 2000 - 2020.  ALl I want to do is start at 1900. End date can be today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default [yearRange](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-yearRange) shows +10 and -10 years from the current date (hence why you see 2000 to 2020)

Try adding:

```
yearRange: '1900:2010'
```

to display the years 1900 to 2010 in the year drop-down.

```
$(function() {
    $('#DOB').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'd MM yy',
        minDate: new Date(1900, 11 - 1, 6),
        yearRange: '1900:2010'

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you choiced dateFormat: 'd MM yy' and range from 1900 to 20* you get the conflict with this values:
"1 February, 10" - is it "01.02.1910" or "01.02.2010"?
May be, if you change the dateFormat the problem would disappeared